# regex - multiple occurrences within match

Tags: regex

Is it possible to find multiple matching groups within the full match using ONLY regex?

Given the text below

> {1234} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. ** Sed
>   iaculis nisi et dapibus consectetur. Vestibulum ** feugiat sapien, sed
>   sagittis magna. Phasellus euismod tempor augue, ** eget dictum mi
>   sagittis sit amet. Quisque sit amet diam vel magna imperdiet pulvinar
>   vel ac lectus. {4321} Lorem ipsum....

Im trying to group all the occurences of ** within the numbers.

I came up with the following:

```
\{\d+\}.+?(\*\*)+.+\{\d.+\}
```

https://regex101.com/r/s746be/2

Which as you can see it only groups the first group because of the lazy question mark or the last if I remove the question mark.

Comment: You mean you want to find 3
 occurrences of `**` in between `{1234}` and `{4321}`? Are you using .NET or PCRE or any other regex engine? Are you going to replace those asterisks?

Comment: Yes, but not only three occurrences, in some full matches might be 4 or more. Im using .NET :)

Comment: But are you replacing them with anything? Do you have access to the code? Is it C# or VB.NET? Also, I think you may use [`(?<={\d+}(?:(?!{\d+}).)*?)\*\*(?=.*?{\d+})`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%7b%5cd%2b%7d%28%3f%3a%28%3f!%7b%5cd%2b%7d%29.%29*%3f%29%5c*%5c*%28%3f%3d.*%3f%7b%5cd%2b%7d%29&i=**+%7b1234%7d+elit.+**+Sed+.+Vestibulum+**+feugiat+augue%2c+**+eget+dictum+nar+vel+ac+lectus.+%7b4321%7d+Lorem+ipsum....+**) but it is not that efficient.

Comment: BTW, you cannot use regex101.com to test .NET regex patterns, it does not support their syntax.

Comment: change the .+? to [^{}]+?  this should avoid it skipping over matching {###}, though you might run into problems if it contains {asdf}

Answer (score 0):

Why not break it down to a few simple steps instead of using a really big inefficient Regex?

You can try doing something like this:

1) Grab the text between `{1234}` and `{4321}` using a simple regex like this:

```
/\{\d+\}(.*?)\{\d+\}/
```

2) Extract the **matched text** between these two delimiters 
3) Run a second global regex search on this matched inner text using a simple regex pattern like so:

```
/\*\*/g
```

Hope this helps